# Import index(.ts|.js) file from folder in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have the following folder structure:

```
src/
   Foo/
      index.ts
   Bar/
      index.ts
   index.ts
```

I want import the module Foo like this `import Foo from "./Foo";` in my src/index.ts file. 
**How is this done?** Because webpack doesn't autoimport the index.ts file from *Foo/* and *Bar/* when I want to "import folder".

Comment: Hi @ZulusK , did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to import `folder` as you mentioned. It's actually done by `webpack` resolve https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions

By default webpack is looking for `.js` and `.json` extensions that means when you import `import Foo from './Foo'` it will try to look `./Foo/index.js` or `./Foo/index.json` if it is found, it is automatically imported. If you need to extend this to typescript you need to specify

```
resolve: {
 extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.ts']
}
```

of course in this way you have to specify `ts-loader` to handle typescript files https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader which will take care of transpilation from typescript when it is imported.